# How to get keyboard above bottom sheet?

Tags: ios, bottom-sheet, material-components

I'm presenting a **MDCBottomSheetController** with a contentViewController that contains an `UITextField`. When the textfield becomes first responder, the keyboard appears and pushes the bottom sheet to its top.

[image: q]

What I want is instead of push the bottom sheet to keyboard's top, it appears above the bottom sheet.

MDCBottomSheetController's API is very limited and don't have anything that I can use to accomplish this behaviour.

The code I'm using to present the bottom sheet is pretty much the basics:

```swift
let contentViewController = SomeViewController()
contentViewController.preferredContentSize = view.frame.size

let bottomSheet = MDCBottomSheetController(contentViewController: otherViewController)
present(bottomSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: facing same problem found any solution on this?

Comment: I am having the same issue, any solution yet? Can we upvote this question